# Mongo Exceeded dept limit while mapreduce function is called

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I been testing a mapreduction operation over huge data set of about 25 million documents. The reduce function is correct and works fine when tested on a small data set.

I get the following error while running the mapreduce over large set

```
"errmsg" : "exception: Exceeded depth limit of 150 when converting js object to BSON. Do you have a cycle?",
"code" : 17279,
"ok" : 0
```

Comment: It sounds like you are "stacking" results in the reducer and therefore is probably not correct. Some code please. Also make sure you have read and fully understand the relevant documentation point : [Requirements of the Reduce Function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function)

Comment: Yes, i tried understanding it and refined few parameters in the reduce function. It was due to huge amount of data being reduced for a given id and i tried to filter them.

Comment: I had a typo like `accounts.push(accounts)` :) that gave me this same error. So the error message seems to be accurate.